# I want to show an alert to the user after no activity for a specific time without using setTimeout function in jquery, is there a way to tackle this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, user-controls, alert

I want to use jquery to show an alert to the user after 10 minutes of not using mouse or keyboard or any other interactivity with the system. And without using setTimeout function.

Please help.

Comment: You don't need setTimeout, but is setInterval allowed?

Comment: *And without using setTimeout function.* Why? It's a good way to get it done. Could you elaborate?